# jQuery toggle on each?

Tags: jquery, toggle

im using jquery to toggle some paragraphs. its pretty easy with just one paragraph but say i have a very generic setup. the second paragraph is initially hidden with css.

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<a href="#" class="more">read more</a>

<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<a href="#" class="more">read more</a>
```

problem is that every time i click one of the "read more" links its shows the every second paragraph. i would just want it to show the second paragraph of the one clicked.

very new to jquery...

Answer (score 2):

First wrap your `<p>` tags in a `div` like so:

```
<div class='toggleable'>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some more text</p>
  <a href="#" class="more">more/less</a>
</div>
```

With some CSS:

```
.toggleable p {
  display: none;
}
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$('.toggleable a.more').click( function() {
  $(this).siblings('p').toggle();
} );
```

Should handle it.

There are other ways to solve this, of course. Maybe you could put the links outside of the div with the text and then do something like: `$('.more').click( function() { $(this).prev().toggle(); } );`... Plenty of approaches. Take a look at jQuery's [DOM traversal](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) methods.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i think that i may have messed up the structure. its

```
<p>some text</p> 
<div class="bio> 
<p>some more text</p> 
</div> <a href="#" class="more">read more</a>  

<p>some text</p> 
<div class="bio> 
<p>some more text</p> 
</div> <a href="#" class="more">read more</a>
```

i need the first `<p>` to show always as sort of an experted. the second `<p>` and any subsequent `<p>` to only show on click of its specific `<a>` thanks for the quick response.