# Issue applying a toggle to each anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have on **click** '**each**' item that was a class of `.toggleDiv` to toggle separately not all at once.

Right now the .toggleDiv on click expands all elements within `.fullSaintDesc` w/ just one click, this is what I don't want it to do - what I want is for EACH element that has a class of `.toggleDiv` to expand the `.fullSaintDesc` but not all together.

If you feel the title of my question is not clear of what I'm asking, feel free to edit it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".toggleDiv").click(function(){
        $(".fullSaintDesc").toggle();return false;
    });   
});
```

html

These classes are being used throughout the page - i want each .toggleDiv to expand on its own not all on ONE click.

```
<p>
  <a class="toggleDiv" href="#">Click here to read more</a>
</p>
<div class="fullSaintDesc">
  <p>blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<!-- eo : fullSaintDesc -->
```

Comment: Your question is still not clear.

Comment: Maybe this question is relevant: [jQuery toggle on each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719558/jquery-toggle-on-each)

Comment: So apparently you only want to toggle the `.fullSaintDesc` element that is somehow related to each `.toggleDiv`... but how are they related? What is your HTML structure?

Comment: i updated my question.. hope thats clearer

Comment: Your update has not improved the question.

Comment: Why don't you post some html ?

Comment: If none of the answers are what you want, provide a snippet of your HTML as well.

Comment: We still don't know how `.fullSaintDesc` is related to `.toggleDiv`. If you don't post your HTML structure, we cannot help and guess at best.

Comment: sorry guys. i updated my answer to reflect my html

Comment: So you always want to toggle the *following* `.fullSaintDesc` element?

Comment: yes! but on its own 'click' - right now once i click on `.toggleDiv` it expands all `.fullSaintDesc` on the page..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to:

```
 $(".toggleDiv .fullSaintDesc").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
 });
```

Without seeing html structure, I can only guess, but this should work:

```
 $(".toggleDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.fullSaintDesc').toggle();
 });
```

Edit 3: Reflecting the last update: (if its consistent)

```
 $(".toggleDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.fullSaintDesc').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: I'd like to see how well this guess did, +1 if this solves the problem.

Comment: How do you know `return false` is not needed?

Comment: this doesn't work. its not what I want. I want `.toggleDiv` to expand .fullSaintDesc but there are several classes on the page that have the class of '.toggleDiv' and i want to expand them on their own click not just one click.

Comment: Felix he's assuming it's a div.

Comment: Felix, at this point anythings possible given the lack of info.

Comment: Edit 3: helped! Thanks. @realshadow - i was missing `.parent()` and `.next()`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".toggleDiv").click(function(event){
   $(this).parent().next('.fullSaintDesc').toggle();
   event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a context to the click.

If you are trying to only toggle a child element of what you click then this should work.

```
$(".toggleDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.fullSaintDesc').toggle();
});
```

#### EDIT Based on updated question:

If the clicked element is an `<a>` then you don't necessarily need the `return false`, a much better way to do it is to use e.preventDefault();`

```
$(".toggleDiv").click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().next(".fullSaintDesc").toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the revised question, you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".toggleDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".fullSaintDesc").toggle();
  });   
});
```

It tells it to start with the anchor that was clicked, move up a level, and then find the next fullSaintDesc, and then toggle that.

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/WG6bJ/1/)